# Postpone standard output in the end

Tags: c++, stdout

Many warning messages (via `std::cout`) might be printed out during the process. Is there a way to postpone the printing of the warning messaged in the end of the program? There are huge amount of the processing information will be printed. I'm planing to have all the warnings together in the end rather than scattered around.

More background:

1. code is already there.
2. there are about 50 warning messages within the code (in case if there is some sort of `delay( )` function, I don't want to add 50 times, would be nice if there is an globally delaye/postpone function for stand output)

Thanks

Comment: You might use a std::stringstream to hold what you want postponed, then display it at end with "std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl'"  Of course this means you will have about 50 warning messages  to touch.

Comment: Warning messages and error messages should be written to `std::cerr` or `std::clog`. Normal output goes to `std::cout`. That way you can redirect one or the other of the output streams (usually stderr) so that its output doesn't mingle with the other stream's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to send everything to a `stringstream`, and then print at the end.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    int i = 5, j = 4;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::cout << i * j << std::endl;
    ss << "success" << std::endl;
    std::cout << j + i * i + j << std::endl;
    ss << "failure" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20                                                                                                                    
33                                                                                                                    
success                                                                                                               
failure
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if you are already a goof and have used `std::cout` everywhere.

Comment: @NickChapman `There are huge amount of the processing information will be printed. I'm planing to have all the warnings together in the end rather than scattered around` I was duplicating the questions requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to delay all printing of `std::cout` what you can do is redirect standard out to a string stream that acts as a buffer. It's pretty simple and avoids all of the `dup`, `dup2`, and piping stuff that one might be inclined to try.

```
#include <sstream>

// Make a buffer for all of your output
std::stringstream buffer;
// Copy std::cout since we're going to replace it temporarily
std::streambuf normal_cout = std::cout.rdbuf();
// Replace std::cout with your bufffer
std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());

// Now your program runs and does its thing writing to std::cout
std::cout << "Additional errors or details" << std::endl;

// Now restore std::cout
std::cout.rdbuf(normal_cout);
// Print the stuff you buffered
std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
```

Also in the future, you should really use a buffer for errors from the start OR at a minimum write errors and logging to `std::cerr` so that your normal runtime print outs aren't cluttered with errors.